# Fresh install of DataStax Cassandra fails with "Install Errored: The installed agent doesn't seem to be responding"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I have 4 fresh Ubuntu 12.04 instances that I am trying to install Cassandra (DataStax Enterprise) on. I have installed and configured everything (from a known good installation procedure) and I am at the point of connecting to OpsCenter and creating a cluster. The OpsCenter agent seems to install fine on 3 out of the 4 nodes, but the one that is actually running OpsCenter (dual-purposed as an OpsCenter and Cassandra node) fails with:

```
Install Errored: The installed agent doesn't seem to be responding
```

In the /var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log I see this:

```
WARN: HTTP request http://10.1.1.26:61621/alive? failed: 503 Service Unavailable
```

This is the node with OpsCenter on it. The opscenterd service is running, 61621 is listening and accessible from other nodes and from itself, I tested wget to that URL and it indeed throws a 503. All other nodes respond with a 200. Not sure what to look for... Any suggestions? Let me know if you need more details - I didn't want to clutter the post with too much useless/irrelevant details...

Comment: Try increasing the logging level and see if there are any more clues in the logs on the problematic node.  Here is a link explaining how to configure OpsCenter, including logging level: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/3.2/webhelp/opsc/configure/opscAdvConfig_r.html.

If anything else seems out of the ordinary in the logs, feel free to include it in the question.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. After some more digging and looking through logs, I noticed that the Cassandra service was referencing localhost which seemed rather odd (I can't find the actual line now, because I deleted the logs, but it was saying it is binding to 127.0.0.1 for something). Long story short, that reference was enough to point me in the right direction - I found out that I had forgotten to modify the listen_address and rpc_address to be the node's IP address (instead of the default localhost). Not sure why it even defaults to localhost, but whatever. It is working now. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad to hear you have it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

i found same error like you.
I did change rules Iptables , and the issue resolve.

[root@ip-172-xxxxx ~]#  iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 61620 -j ACCEPT

[root@ip-172-xxxxx ~]# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 50031 -j ACCEPT

[root@ip-172-xxxxx  ~]# iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 50031 -j ACCEPT

[root@ip-172-xxxxx  ~]# iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 61620 -j ACCEPT
iptables -L
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:61620

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:50031

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ddi-tcp-1

Lucky!

Comment: I mean if you run Linux base instance EC2, maybe default firewall setting of iptables is DISABLE ports use request for OpsCenter : 8888, 61620, 50031. We need open they again